# Swift adding annotations on map

Tags: ios, swift, annotations

Trying to make some annotations on the map. But can't get around it. the code I'm using is

```
 // Names
 names = ["Ben", "Big", "Hawk", "Enot", "Wiltons", "Scott's", "The Laughing"]

        // Latitudes, Longitudes
        coordinates = [
            [51.519066, -0.135200],
            [51.513446, -0.125787],
            [51.465314, -0.214795],
            [51.507747, -0.139134],
            [51.509878, -0.150952],
            [51.501041, -0.104098],
            [51.485411, -0.162042],
            [51.513117, -0.142319]
        ]
```

Comment: Well this just look like a data structure. What have tried to actually add annotations to your map view? How do you create the map view?

Comment: You need to show any tries. What Map are you using?

Comment: The mapview follows users location (created his way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrdIL44T6FQ ) but i want to put these as annotations on the map only. i tried with string but couldn't make anything happend..   var names:[String]!
    var descriptions:[String]!
    var coordinates:[AnyObject]!
    var currentRestaurantIndex: Int = 0
    var Locationmanager = CLLocationManager()

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The function addAnnotation  takes an array of type CLLocation, which is what you should use. So make the array look like this to initialize CLLocation objects. I assume you already have a working rendered map, mapView object, etc.

```
let coords = [  CLLocation(latitude: xxxx, longitude: xxxx),
   CLLocation(latitude: xxx, longitude: xxx),
   CLLocation(latitude: xxx, longitude:xxx)
    ];
```

here is a function that can take that array, and loops through each element and adds it as an annotation to the mapView (not yet rendered)

```
func addAnnotations(coords: [CLLocation]){
        for coord in coords{
            let CLLCoordType = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coord.coordinate.latitude,
                                                      longitude: coord.coordinate.longitude);
            let anno = MKPointAnnotation();
            anno.coordinate = CLLCoordType;
            mapView.addAnnotation(anno);
        }

    }
```

Finally, you need to use the `MKMapViewDelegate` delegate to use one of its automatically called methods, when a new annotation is added, so we can queue and render it. This would be unnecessary if you were adding annotations once, but it is good to have them added like this so you can manipulate them later.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation{
        return nil;
    }else{
        let pinIdent = "Pin";
        var pinView: MKPinAnnotationView;
        if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(pinIdent) as? MKPinAnnotationView {
            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation;
            pinView = dequeuedView;
        }else{
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: pinIdent);

        }
        return pinView;
    }
}
```

Do not just add this code and expect it to work, make sure you incorporate it correctly, in the right areas of your project. Do comment if you have further questions.

**UPDATE:**

remember to inherit the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol into the controller your using.

Make sure you actually call `addAnnotations`, in `ViewDidLoad`, and pass through `coords` array. Which can be defined in `ViewDidLoad`.

Make sure the mapView method is not in ViewDidLoad but a member of the controller.

Comment: I used the code and changed values to the right ones. But im getting (immutable value "coords" was never used). Im putting the first code in viewdidload, is it right or am i absolutely lost?

Comment: You need to call the function addAnnotation and put the array through as argument.

Comment: i am going to update my answer with a list of things to bear in mind, tell me how it goes.

Comment: How do i call addAnnotations in ViewDidLoad?

Comment: what do you mean? just call it...?

Comment: like self.coords.  ..?

Comment: addAnnotations(coords)

Comment: tried mapView.addAnnotations(coords), error said "cannot convert value of type [anyObject]! to expect argument type MKannotation"

Comment: Why mapView? It is not a member of mapView, its a function we made :) sorry,  I should have called it something a little more diverse!

Comment: there is the addAnnotation() method which belongs to mapView, in the addAnnotationSSSS function which we made (attempting to stressing the plural there, not actually SSSS..)

Comment: Yeah,in the function "addannotation" we made mapview.addannotation.. But still not getting anywhere since im not getting the hang of it .. yet.. :/

Answer (score 1):

Add Simple annotation with title Swift 5.0

```
    let addAnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    addAnotation.title = "YOUR TITLE"
    addAnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: [YOUR LATITIUDE], longitude: [YOUR LONGITUDE])
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(addAnotation)
```

---

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    
    guard annotation is MKPointAnnotation else { return nil }

    let identifier = "Annotation"
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
    } else {
        annotationView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    return annotationView
}
```