# How can I add annotations for every Pizzeria in a city? (Xcode)

Tags: annotations, location, mapkit

I'm working on an app that according to your location it'll show all pizzerias near you. I would like to know how I can add annotations for every pizzeria in a city, with the name, phone number, and address

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some example code.

Comment: Your question is a bit large in scope, look more into adding annotations in MapKit as per this question:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39469529/swift-adding-annotations-on-map

Comment: Dou you want to ask apple for Pizzerias or do you want to bring your own data with you?

Comment: I want to ask apple to show all pizzerias in a city